# Conditional Data Frame String Split Based on Second White Space

Tags: r, string, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have a data frame that I want to split the first column's text string into two columns but only after the second whitespace in the sequence.  Here is a sample:

```
                           test22 Ticker
1        Current SharePrice $6.57    MFM
2               Current NAV $7.11    MFM
3 Current Premium/Discount -7.59%    MFM
4        52WkAvg SharePrice $6.55    MFM
5               52WkAvg NAV $7.21    MFM
6 52WkAvg Premium/Discount -9.19%    MFM
```

Essentially, if the end result would be a data frame with three columns total and the price/% field being its own separate column.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using `dplyr` and `stringr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <-
  tibble(test22 = c("Current SharePrice $6.57",
                    "Current NAV $7.11",
                    "Current Premium/Discount -7.59%",
                    "52WkAvg SharePrice $6.55",
                    "52WkAvg NAV $7.21",
                    "52WkAvg Premium/Discount -9.19%"),
         Ticker = "MFM")

data %>% 
  mutate(category = str_replace(test22, "^(.+ .+) (.+)$", "\\1"),
         price_pc = str_replace(test22, "^(.+ .+) (.+)$", "\\2"))


# A tibble: 6 x 4
test22                          Ticker category                 price_pc
<chr>                           <chr>  <chr>                    <chr>   
1 Current SharePrice $6.57        MFM    Current SharePrice       $6.57   
2 Current NAV $7.11               MFM    Current NAV              $7.11   
3 Current Premium/Discount -7.59% MFM    Current Premium/Discount -7.59%  
4 52WkAvg SharePrice $6.55        MFM    52WkAvg SharePrice       $6.55   
5 52WkAvg NAV $7.21               MFM    52WkAvg NAV              $7.21   
6 52WkAvg Premium/Discount -9.19% MFM    52WkAvg Premium/Discount -9.19%
```

**EDIT: Explanation of the Regex used**

Ignoring the brackets for a second:

**^** = start of the string

**.** = any character except a new line

**+** = at least one of the previous character (in this case, any character except a new line)

**$** = end of the string

So `"^(.+ .+) (.+)$"` looks for strings which start, have some characters, then a space, then some characters, then a space, then some more characters, then end.

The brackets are added as "capture groups", meaning that the query "remembers" the part of the string which is represented by these brackets, and can be extracted by referring to the order of the brackets. Hence `"\\1"` returns what was captured by the first bracket, and `"\\2"` returns what was captured by the second.

A good resource for learning Regex is [Regexr](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: No worries @js80. Some upvote/chosen answer love would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain the syntax: ^(.+ .+) (.+)$", "\\1"?

Comment: @js80 have added an explanation above, since it was too wordy for a comment. In short: it's Regex.

Answer (score 1):

One option in base [r](/questions/tagged/r) is to create a delimiter `,` with `sub` and then use `read.csv`:

```
out <- cbind(read.csv(text = sub(" (\\S+)$", ",\\1", df1$test22), 
       header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), df1[2])
out
#.                       V1     V2 Ticker
#1       Current SharePrice  $6.57    MFM
#2              Current NAV  $7.11    MFM
#3 Current Premium/Discount -7.59%    MFM
#4       52WkAvg SharePrice  $6.55    MFM
#5              52WkAvg NAV  $7.21    MFM
#6 52WkAvg Premium/Discount -9.19%    MFM
```

---

Or using `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
     extract(test22, into = c("V1", "V2"), "^(\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\s+(.*)")
#                        V1     V2 Ticker
#1       Current SharePrice  $6.57    MFM
#2              Current NAV  $7.11    MFM
#3 Current Premium/Discount -7.59%    MFM
#4       52WkAvg SharePrice  $6.55    MFM
#5              52WkAvg NAV  $7.21    MFM
#6 52WkAvg Premium/Discount -9.19%    MFM
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(test22 = c("Current SharePrice $6.57", "Current NAV $7.11", 
  "Current Premium/Discount -7.59%", "52WkAvg SharePrice $6.55", 
 "52WkAvg NAV $7.21", "52WkAvg Premium/Discount -9.19%"), Ticker = c("MFM", 
 "MFM", "MFM", "MFM", "MFM", "MFM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `strsplit`

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$test22, '\\s(?!.*\\s)', perl = TRUE)), 
           Ticker=df$Ticker)
#                         X1     X2 Ticker
# 1       Current SharePrice  $6.57    MFM
# 2              Current NAV  $7.11    MFM
# 3 Current Premium/Discount -7.59%    MFM
# 4       52WkAvg SharePrice  $6.55    MFM
# 5              52WkAvg NAV  $7.21    MFM
# 6 52WkAvg Premium/Discount -9.19%    MFM
```

Or using `gsub`

```
gsub('.*\\s.*?\\s(.*)','\\1', df$test22, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "$6.57"  "$7.11"  "-7.59%" "$6.55"  "$7.21"  "-9.19%"
# or if factors
# gsub('.*\\s.*?\\s(.*)','\\1', as.character(df$test22), perl = TRUE)
```

The advantage of the second is that it truly considers the second spacing character (as opposed to last spacing).

Comment: I'm getting the following error with this but I am applying it to a large data frame:  Error in strsplit(df6$test22, "\\s(?!.*\\s)", perl = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument

Comment: @js80 Mayber because you have factors. Try: `as.character(df$test22)` in `strsplit` instead of `df$test22`. Or maybe try the scond option.